# Parcel Bundler " no such file or directory " for font

Tags: css, font-face, parcel

I am using parcel bundler to build a website ( first time I'm using it ). Everything worked just fine until I tried to import a font with " @font-face " and " src: url("some-path").

Error: No such file or directory, so basically can't find the right path for the font.

My folder structure:

root/src

root/src/assets

root/src/assets/css ( which contains a main.scss and some subfolders for others.scss )

root/src/assets/fonts/fontname.woff

In my _fonts.scss file:

```
    font-family: 'TTFirs';
    src: url('../../fonts/TTFirsNeue-Regular.woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
```

I read aboute absolute/relative path in parcel documentary, and their solutions is to use an absolute path like so:

`src: url('src/assets/fonts/TTFirsNeue-Regular.woff2');`

...but still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of parcel are you using ?